# Multiline string as XML

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I see that people got this trick in pre-vs2015 for writing multi-line strings. And there is question and nice answers here already. My question is not whether this possible but what are the implications of it?

People do

```
Dim s As String = 
<a>
    SELECT f1, f2, f3
    FROM t1
    WHERE f4 = 10
</a>.Value
```

It is readable alright. It has no capability of carriage return without special handling. But I suspect, it is extra processing at runtime and what about string interning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is a overhead but i don't think it's that much :

There is a ctor call to [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341343%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with it's associated XName (via implicit conversion from string) it's only content is the text (a string as object).
The ctor itself don't seem to do much too from what I can see in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,3478); testing the content type against XNode first then string and just setting the internal content field to the string.

Value property works on the same principle apparently.

That string also seems to be interned because calling [String.IsInterned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the whole thing returns the string and not null.

And past that expression evaluation the XElement isn't used anymore so it's directly eligible for collection by GC (probably freed in gen0).

So to conclude I'd rather say nothing to really worry about unless performance is critical (but then only a real profiling can tell if the overhead comes from that or elsewhere).

Comment: Yes, one day I will time it :o) Good research. Thanks!